# Why is the spyOn function in the test not working with sendGrid?

Tags: node.js, graphql, jestjs, sendgrid, ts-jest

I am setting up a graphql server with `graphql-yoga` and `prisma using Typescript. When a user signs up, an email with a link for validation will be sent to the given email address.
Everything is working fine, but i want to write a test for the mutation before refactoring the functionality, which checks if the 'send' function of SendGrid hast been called.

I tried spying on the function with `jest.spyOn`, but all I get is an error, that comes from not providing an API key for SendGrid in the tesing environment.

I have used spyOn before, and it worked, though this is the first time I am using jest with Typescript.

SignUp Mutation

```
import * as sgMail from '@sendgrid/mail';

sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.MAIL_API_KEY);

export const Mutation = {
    async signUpUser(parent, { data }, { prisma }, info) {
        [...]
        const emailData = {
            from: 'test@test.de',
            to: `${user.email}`,
            subject: 'Account validation',
            text: `validation Id: ${registration.id}`
        };
        await sgMail.send(emailData);

        return user;
    }
}
```

Trying spyOn

```
import * as sgMail from '@sendgrid/mail';

const signUpUserMutation = gql`
    mutation($data: ValidationInput) {
        signUpUser (data: $data) {
            id
            email
        }
    }
`;

it('should send a registration email, with a link, containing the id of the registration', async () => {
    spyOn(sgMail, "send").and.returnValue(Promise.resolve('Success'));
    const variables = {
        data: {
            email: "test@test.de",
            password: "anyPassword"
        }
    };

    await client.mutate({ mutation: signUpUserMutation, variables});
    expect(sgMail.send).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Running the test gives me:

> Error: GraphQL error: Unauthorized

Commenting out the function call of send in the mutation and running the test gives me:

> Error: expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
>
> Expected spy to have been called, but it was not called.

Comment: I haven't tried to see if this is causing the issue, but `spyOn` is an undocumented legacy function from `Jasmine` that still works in `Jest` but probably shouldn't (you can use the `--errorOnDeprecated` to throw an error if deprecated API's are being used in your tests)...use [`jest.spyOn`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestspyonobject-methodname) instead

Answer (score 1):

You don't mock `@sendgrid/mail` module in a correct way. That's why the error happened. Here is the solution without using `GraphQL` test client. But you can use `GraphQL` test client to test your `GraphQL` resolver and `GraphQL` Schema after you mock `@sendgrid/mail` module correctly.

`mutations.ts`:

```js
import * as sgMail from '@sendgrid/mail';

sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.MAIL_API_KEY || '');

export const Mutation = {
  async signUpUser(parent, { data }, { prisma }, info) {
    const user = { email: 'example@gmail.com' };
    const registration = { id: '1' };
    const emailData = {
      from: 'test@test.de',
      to: `${user.email}`,
      subject: 'Account validation',
      text: `validation Id: ${registration.id}`
    };
    await sgMail.send(emailData);

    return user;
  }
};
```

`mutations.spec.ts`:

```js
import { Mutation } from './mutations';
import * as sgMail from '@sendgrid/mail';
import { RequestResponse } from 'request';

jest.mock('@sendgrid/mail', () => {
  return {
    setApiKey: jest.fn(),
    send: jest.fn()
  };
});

describe('Mutation', () => {
  describe('#signUpUser', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      jest.resetAllMocks();
    });
    it('should send a registration email, with a link, containing the id of the registration', async () => {
      (sgMail.send as jest.MockedFunction<typeof sgMail.send>).mockResolvedValueOnce([{} as RequestResponse, {}]);
      const actualValue = await Mutation.signUpUser({}, { data: {} }, { prisma: {} }, {});
      expect(actualValue).toEqual({ email: 'example@gmail.com' });
      expect(sgMail.send).toBeCalledWith({
        from: 'test@test.de',
        to: 'example@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Account validation',
        text: `validation Id: 1`
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/56379585/mutations.spec.ts (12.419s)
  Mutation
    #signUpUser
      ✓ should send a registration email, with a link, containing the id of the registration (23ms)

--------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File          |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
--------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files     |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 mutations.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
--------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        14.315s
```

Here is the completed demo: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/56379585